# Is it possible to show static fields in the Unity Editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote little script yesterday but it isn't working. (Serialize fields isn't showing in unity and few errors eg. I can't use reference to non-static member (serialize Field)). Can You help me please.

Eg.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class sExample : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField] public static GameObject gameObj;
  public void serializeUse()
  {
    //Do something with gameObj
  }
}
public class serializeEx : NetworkBehaviour
{
  public void Update()
  {
    If (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
      sExample.serializeUse()
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work.
I think that you can't use static, when you want to expose something to the Editor.

```
using UnityEngine;
[Serializable]
public class sExample : MonoBehaviour
{
  [SerializeField] public GameObject gameObj;
  public void serializeUse()
  {
    //Do something with gameObj
  }
}

public class serializeEx : NetworkBehaviour
{
  public void Update()
  {
    If (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
      sExample.serializeUse()
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Statics seem to work for JavaScript as mentioned in [this](https://answers.unity.com/answers/620310/view.html) post.
To make this work you'll have to switch to the debug view in the inspector.
Like in the image shown below:

[image: image showing the debug view]

**Edit2:**

The explanation what the Serializeable does is taken from the unity [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html).

> The Serializable attribute lets you embed a class with sub properties
>   in the inspector.
>
> You can use this to display variables in the inspector similar to how
>   a Vector3 shows up in the inspector. The name and a triangle to expand
>   its properties. To do this you need create a class that derives from
>   System.Object and give it the Serializable attribute. In JavaScript
>   the Serializable attribute is implicit and not necessary.

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
class Test : System.Object
{
    public int p = 5;
    public Color c = Color.white;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this [Serializeable] is doing? I am new in c#

Comment: sure i can! :) i edited the answer. If my answer fixed your problem, i'd be glad if you accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

The `[SerializeField]` attribute doesn't support static fields and reference types.